# Do all even potentials produce periodic motion?

Tags: classical-mechanics, potential-energy, oscillators, non-linear-systems

Consider a non-relativistic point particle of mass $m$ in 1D under the action of only conservative forces. Then by Newton's second law, the equation of motion is $$m\ddot{x}(t)=-U'(x(t)).$$
Now, do all potentials that satisfy $U(x)=U(-x)$ produce periodic motion? If so, how can we prove it?

It seems to be the case for simple harmonic motion, where $U \propto x^2$, the Duffing oscillator where $U \propto x^4$, and the simple pendulum, where $U \propto \cos (x)$. And it seems that all odd potentials produce non periodic motion, for the case in which the potential is a linear function, which produces motion with constant acceleration.

If it's true that all even potentials produce periodic motion, then what is the physical reason for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not all even potentials produce periodic motion. For example $U=-|x|$ is even but does not produce periodic motion. You listed $U \propto x^2$ as one with oscillations, but that is not true in general since $U=-x^2$ does not produce periodic motion.

Potentials which produce periodic motion have local minima, and the oscillations are produced near the local minimum. Being even does not itself produce oscillation and being odd does not prevent it.

For example, $U=x^3-x$ is an odd potential which has a local minimum at $x=1/\sqrt{3}$. If your initial conditions are a sufficiently small initial velocity and an initial position sufficiently close to the minimum, then you will get oscillation. Note, this oscillation will not be simple harmonic oscillation.

Comment: So, if being odd does not prevent a potential to produce periodic motion, is there an example of an odd potential that produces periodic motion?

Comment: @DonAl, how about $U \propto \sin(x)$? It is odd, and $\ddot{x}+\cos(x) = 0$ is an example of periodic motion.

Comment: @Dale this equation $m\ddot x+ 2x=0$ produce periodic motion ?

Comment: @Don Al yes, $x^3-x$ is odd and oscillates around the minimum at $x=1/\sqrt{3}$ as long as your initial conditions are reasonable close and slow.

Comment: @Eli yes. . . .